# How did Ki-ja the Hakuryuu (the White Dragon) get this scar?

Tags: yona-of-the-dawn

In the preview for [Episode 10](http://www.animerush.tv/Akatsuki-no-Yona-episode-10/) of [Akatsuki no Yona](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_no_Yona), it was shown that Ki-ja had this scar on his back.

[image: Ki-ja]

Answer (score 4):

It is revealed in **Chapter 70.5 - Extra Chapter: Upon That Back** of the manga and in the OVA **Akatsuki no Yona - Sono Se niwa**.

> It was caused by the previous White dragon, who was also Ki-ja's father, at the moment of his birth as a *mark of desperation*.
>
>  [image: Chapter 70.5 - Page 25]

Comment: Sh*t. And i was happy at least the white dragon wasn't abused as a child.